# SSO Excel Add-In

Tags: azure, office365, single-sign-on, excel-addins

I made an excel add-in and followed the docs to the letter. I have a manifest which validates, works on localhost when side-loaded, and can retrieve the SSO user name.

Relevant manifest part looks like this:

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
  <Id>GUID</Id>
  <Resource>api://xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx</Resource>
  <Scopes>
    <Scope>openid</Scope>
    <Scope>email</Scope>
    <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
    <Scope>user.read</Scope>
    <Scope>profile</Scope>
  </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>
```

I went through all the steps with adding a resource on azure, consented to all permissions as admin, and it all seems to work... until I deploy it to my org. The only error is shown below.

[image]

I found this in audit logs:

```
Consent to Application
ApplicationManagement
Microsoft.Online.RestServices.Common.Provider.Query.InvalidRequestException
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! If your 'id' in the manifest is incorrect, MS will still validate the manifest, but you will see the error I described. Fix it by using the correct client-id, found in the overview section of your app in azure.